# SQL SUM if field is a specific value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL Query that used to have `inclusive <> '1'` as a clause but I had to remove it to ensure I pick up all the data but I still need to count the value of the `inclusive` field in the SUM

Is it possible to make the `SUM(customer_cost) as customer_total` not include rows where `inclusive <> '1'`

```
$callChargesSql = "SELECT 
                customer,
                source,
                source_name,
                calltype,
                SUM(customer_cost) as customer_total,
                SUM(cost) as cost,
                SUM(recording_cost) as recording_cost,
                SUM(recording_customer) as recording_customer
            FROM
                billing_calldata
            WHERE
                (
                    customer = '".db_string($result["sequence"])."' OR
                    customer IN 
                    (
                        SELECT 
                            sequence 
                        FROM 
                            customer 
                        WHERE 
                            resellerid = '".db_string($result["sequence"])."'
                    )
                ) AND
                (
                    (
                        MONTH(timestamp) = '".db_string($calls["month"])."' AND
                        YEAR(timestamp) = '".db_string($calls["year"])."'
                    ) OR
                    status = 'y'
                )
            GROUP BY customer, source, calltype
            ORDER BY customer, timestamp ASC;";
```

Comment: Use parameters!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL you can use `IF` statement within `SUM` operator like:

```
SUM(IF(inclusive = '1',customer_cost, 0)) as customer_total
```

Below simplified example:

```
select 
    customer_id,
    sum(customer_cost) as total_customer_cost,
    sum(if(inclusive=1, customer_cost, 0)) as inclusive_customer_cost
from billing_calldata
group by customer_id
;
```

Here you can test it: [SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=7db028a69ac6778d19181d54f9d0d2cb&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)

In my test you can

Comment: Sure @charlie it will.

Comment: I just tried, and it's returning figures the same as before but when I add `inclusive <> '1'` back in the where clause, it shows different figures

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this: `SUM(case when inclusive = '1' then customer_cost else 0 end) as customer_total`

In your example query:

```
$callChargesSql = "SELECT 
                customer,
                source,
                source_name,
                calltype,
                SUM(case when inclusive = '1' then customer_cost else 0 end) as customer_total,
                SUM(cost) as cost,
                SUM(recording_cost) as recording_cost,
                SUM(recording_customer) as recording_customer
            FROM
                billing_calldata
            WHERE
                (
                    customer = '".db_string($result["sequence"])."' OR
                    customer IN 
                    (
                        SELECT 
                            sequence 
                        FROM 
                            customer 
                        WHERE 
                            resellerid = '".db_string($result["sequence"])."'
                    )
                ) AND
                (
                    (
                        MONTH(timestamp) = '".db_string($calls["month"])."' AND
                        YEAR(timestamp) = '".db_string($calls["year"])."'
                    ) OR
                    status = 'y'
                )
            GROUP BY customer, source, calltype
            ORDER BY customer, timestamp ASC;";
```

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev CASE,,,WHEN...END works in MySQL too, I believe.

Comment: yes, the `case` is apply before the `group by` has it's effect